# Increased for vs increased by

Tags: grammaticality

> For both experiments, method A has increased the number of correct
>   solutions found for 72.33% and 75%, compared to method B.

vs

> For both experiments, method A has increased the number of correct
>   solutions found by 72.33% and 75%, compared to method B.

may I know which one is grammatical?

Answer (score 2):

"By" is correct.

I would also not use "for both" in your introductory clause, rather

> In these two experiments, method A increased the number of correct solutions found by 72.33% and 75%, compared to method B.

Using "both" implies the two experiments had identical results, which the rest of the sentence contradicts by giving two different values.

Comment: I think there *are* two experiments- one that yielded a 72.3% increase and one a 75% increase, and method A increased the number of correct solutions in both of them.  I'd add a "*respectively*" after the 75%.  Or better, "In each experiment, method A increased the number of correct solutions found ..."

Comment: @Jim To use "respectively" there need to be two lists, like "in experiment A and experiment B we measured 5% and 10% improvement, respectively. "

Comment: The way I read the statement I think there are two experiments.  Each experiment uses both Method A and Method B to find a number of correct solutions.  In the first experiment Method A found 72.3% more correct solutions than Method B and the second experiment Method A found 75% more correct solutions. So you can say that in the two experiments Method A found, respectively, 72.3% (Exp 1) and 75% (Exp 2) more solutions than Method B.  Anyway that's how I understood OP's sentence.

Comment: @Jim, I agree there were two experiments. But "respectively" means you're listing the results in the same order you've listed the experiments. Since s/he didn't list the experiments in any particular order, there's no reason to use "respectively".

Comment: If I say "the three cars are red, green, and blue [respectively]" I just know I have a red car, a green car, and a blue car. Adding "respectively" tells me nothing extra. If I say, "John, Bill, and Mary's cars are red, green, and blue, respectively" then I know John's car is red, Bill's is green, and Mary's is blue, because "respectively" tells me the colors are listed in the same order as the corresponding owners.

Comment: Actually in the first case, it *does* tell you something.  It tells you that the 3 cars are each a different color as opposed to all three being multicolored.  And the same here, it tells us that the 2 results quoted came, one each, from the 2 experiments cited, rather than each experiment producing identical sets of (2) result values, (For example from multiple measurements taken during each experiment)